# pandas standalone series and from dataframe different behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Here is my code and warning message. If I change `s` to be a standalone `Series` by using `s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))`, there will no such errors. Using Python 2.7 on Windows.

It seems Series created from standalone and Series created from a column of a data frame are different behavior? Thanks.

My purpose is to change the Series value itself, other than change on a copy.

**Source code**,

```
import pandas as pd

sample = pd.read_csv('123.csv', header=None, skiprows=1,
       dtype={0:str, 1:str, 2:str, 3:float})
sample.columns = pd.Index(data=['c_a', 'c_b', 'c_c', 'c_d'])
sample['c_d'] = sample['c_d'].astype('int64')
s = sample['c_d']
#s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s.iloc[i] > 0:
        s.iloc[i] = s.iloc[i] + 1
    else:
        s.iloc[i] = s.iloc[i] - 1
```

**Warning message**,

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:132: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

**Content of 123.csv**,

```
c_a,c_b,c_c,c_d
hello,python,numpy,0.0
hi,python,pandas,1.0
ho,c++,vector,0.0
ho,c++,std,1.0
go,c++,std,0.0
```

**Edit 1**, seems lambda solution does not work, tried to print `s` before and after, the same value,

```
import pandas as pd

sample = pd.read_csv('123.csv', header=None, skiprows=1,
       dtype={0:str, 1:str, 2:str, 3:float})
sample.columns = pd.Index(data=['c_a', 'c_b', 'c_c', 'c_d'])
sample['c_d'] = sample['c_d'].astype('int64')
s = sample['c_d']
print s
s.apply(lambda x:x+1 if x>0 else x-1)
print s

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
Name: c_d, dtype: int64
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
```

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `s = sample['c_d']`, if you make a change to the value of `s` then your original Dataframe `sample` also changes. That's why you got the warning.

You can do `s = sample[c_d].copy()` instead, so that changing the value of `s` doesn't change the value of `c_d` column of the Dataframe `sample`.

Comment: Thanks iparjono, vote up. I may read your message wrong, here is the warning message I got -- "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame", I think it means I am changing a copy of column `c_d`, correct? But you mentioned, I am changing data frame itself -- "If you make a change to the value of s then your sample also changes. That's why you got the warning"? A bit confused, if you could clarify, it will be great. :)

Comment: I might also be confused by the message. However, doing `s = sample[c_d]` and `s = sample[c_d].copy` resulting different effect on your original Dataframe `sample`.

Comment: I have got your idea, thanks iparjono for the patience to explain to me. Mark you reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use apply function instead:

```
s.apply(lambda x:x+1 if x>0 else x-1)
```

Comment: Thanks Shahram, how do you explain my code has no warning if I use a standalone Series, comparing to using a column of a data frame as a Series?

Comment: BTW, Shahram, it seems your code does not work as expected, see Edit 1 section for my trial. Thanks.

Comment: The message was coming because you were changing the value of Series as a copy of a Dataframe's column. Of course you didn't get for the standalone Series.

Comment: @iparjono, thanks for the confirm, so the message means I changed the value of Series `s` (where `s = sample['c_d']`), not the data frame column `c_d`, since `s` is already a copy of data frame column `c_d`, correct?